# how does "wait for completion" workflow activity works?

Tags: workflow, servicenow

In Service now how does "wait for completion" in workflow activity works?

Does it mean it will wait for task to be flagged "active" false? Or will it wait for the task state to be "complete" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it will wait for the child task to have it's state changed to one of closed complete, closed incomplete or closed skipped. You can see how this is implemented by looking at the "SNC - Run parent workflows" business rule in ServiceNow. For more info and a discussion on this check out this discussion on the ServiceNow Community Site.

https://community.servicenow.com/thread/150575